# System.IO.FileLoadException from WshShell.Exec in Classic ASP on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp-classic, permissions, iis-7.5, .net

I’m using the DidiSoft OpenPGP for .NET library to compile C# into an exe that gets executed by Classic ASP. The goal is to update the security on this legacy website to use PGP. It’s an old site so we can’t rewrite it without significant cost.

The reason I tried to use this library was that when we would call compiled C# EXE’s that referenced:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

I would get a blank output in ASP, and IIS would throw an error in Event Log similar to this:

```
Faulting application name: PGPTest.exe, version: 1.0.0.51, time stamp: 0x52f28ee5 
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116 
Exception code: 0xe0434352 
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f 
Faulting process id: 0x5f08 
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf22a83ae734f4 
Faulting application path: d:\inetpub\_bin\[redacted website name]\PGPTest.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll 
Report Id: 789751fa-8e9b-11e3-87e1-0050568e508f
Application: PGPTest.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
Stack: 
   at PGPTest.Program.Main(System.String[])
================
.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.1008 - There was a failure initializing profiling API attach infrastructure.  This process will not allow a profiler to attach.  HRESULT: 0x80004005
Process ID (decimal): 24328.  Message ID: [0x2509].
```

So when I use either the DidiSoft OpenPGP or System.Security.Cryptography I get errors.

In Classic ASP the application is called with:

```
WshShell.Exec(%pathtoexe%)
```

We **do receive output IF** if we change the Application Pool to run under LocalSystem instead of NetworkService. So it seems to be related to permissions somehow.

Our server is running:

- Server 2008 R2
- .NET 4.0

We're assuming running the application pool under LocalSystem is unsafe; is this correct?
Any ideas on how we can get this to work?

Thank you

**Update:** The author of the library has confirmed to me that it does use System.Security.Cryptography for some of its algorithms.

**Update 2:** To ulluoink: If you read this at all you'd realize that this DOES in-fact have to do with Classic ASP. How do I know you ask? Because when moving the code from a C# app that Classic ASP executes into a ASP.NET 4 Web API app, the SAME EXACT CODE on the exact same server works just fine. It appears to be a permissions issue tied DIRECTLY to Classic ASP's execution privileges.

So, the current work around is to deploy our code that references System.Security.Cryptography to the same server in an ASP.NET Web API app. We're POSTing to the ASP.NET app in Classic ASP; specifically sending data serialized with this: http://www.aspjson.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes running a site exposed to the internet as LocalSystem is unsafe. You can use filemon or processmon while loading the page to see which files need permissions from which users.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the server's running a few dozen websites so tracking that down is nearly impossible. Any idea what the file location of System.Security.dll is that it's trying to access?

Comment: Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

07/03/2013  09:54 PM           262,144 System.Security.dll
               1 File(s)        262,144 bytes

 Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

09/11/2013  10:33 PM           280,168 System.Security.dll
               1 File(s)        280,168 bytes

 Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

07/03/2013  09:53 PM           262,144 System.Security.dll
               1 File(s)        262,144 bytes

Comment: I took ownership of the System.Security.dll's in the Framework64 and Framework folders (2.0 and 4.0). When I added the Network Service account it got Read / Read and Execute permissions. Changing all 4 of the Dll's permissions however didn't help.